# Enable Log messages from real device on Logcat 

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, logcat

For my android app development, I am trying to get logcat messages from my real device (when starting an app on it from eclipse) and not just from my emulator.

Does someone know how to enable such a feature?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to enable USB Debugging on your device. Go to settings, applications, development and tick "USB Debugging". Then when your device is connected by USB you can see its name in DDMS as if it was another emulator.

Comment: in a strange way, it doesn't...usb-debugging has already been enabled

Comment: aaaaaah, I found it out :) I just had to click at the device in DDMS to enable logcat for it. Thanks for the hint :) Reading can be useful ;-)

Comment: I have the same problem, not getting logs from device through logcat..I clicked on the device entry on DDMS but still no fruit for me..:(

Comment: You don't need to use the DDMS perspective to switch devices: you can use Window/Show View/Other/Android/Devices to get the list in a tab on the Java perspective.

Answer (score 4):

It works like the emulator, use the ddms or eclipse plugin to get the logcat from your app running on devices.

Otherwise you have always the options to use a `Log Collector` app (download a free one from Market), you can tell your users to use such app if they want to send you the log.

Comment: Mhhh, while using my emulator I get LogCat entries, but when I start the same app at the same way on my phone I don't see anything

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, you have to explicitly enable debugging on a real device.

- It could be that a device android image is built with debuggable property as off (you can check that by running `adb shell getprop`). 
  In this case you need to declare your app as debuggable in the AndroidManifest.xml (`<application .... android:debuggable="true">`).
  This is actually explicitly stated in the Android Dev Guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) (Under Set up your device for development, which also mentions turning on "USB Debugging" and a couple more tweaks).
- Some devices (e.g. Motorola Cliq) disable by default all verbose and debug log messages.
  For it to work, you must run `adb shell setprop log.debug_level 1` on the device and only then debug messages work (that is, until you power-cycle the device).

Comment: everything on http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html has been done already...this is very strange...

Comment: What device are you working on? 
Do you see any logs, or is it just your app's logs are missing?
Did you try to emit logs at all log-levels?

Comment: @adamk samsung galaxy ace. logcat doesn't want to connect to my hardware no matter what I try

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install first a suitable usb driver for your android device then your eclipse will recognize your device as an android device and start debugging